# Teradata Sub-string Before and After certain character

Tags: sql, teradata

I am looking for a way to extract text that is before and after a certain character in Teradata. For example, I have a column that is consistent except for the word in the middle - which I want to extract.

I have these two examples:

1. "Customer Activated Account DD: ABCD, ON DATE XXXX"
2. "Customer Activated Account DD: EFGH, ON DATE XXXX"

I need the text that exists right after ":" and before "," - in this case ABCD or EFGH. So far I have `SUBSTRING (column FROM POSITION ('DD: ' IN column) +4)` but that returns everything after the ":" like `ABCD, ON DATE XXXX`.

Comment: Have you tried `SUBSTRING(column FROM POSITION(‘DD: ‘ IN column) FOR 4)`?

Comment: That would work if the characters I am extracting were always be the same size. I ended up finding a work around by doing what I did above first, putting everything in a temp table and then using: SUBSTRING([COLUMN],0, CHARINDEX(',',[COLUMN])) AS COLUMN_NAME

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expression to extract the information between ':' & ',' for the given requirement.

```
SELECT regexp_substr('Customer Activated Account DD: EFGH, ON DATE XXXX','[^:,]+',1,2);
SELECT regexp_substr('Customer Activated Account DD: ABCD, ON DATE XXXX','[^:,]+',1,2);
```

[^:,] is used to split the string and then second position word is the required output

Answer (score 0):

I agree that regexp_substr is better in this case. Would your delimiter however be fixed, strtok can be quite helpful. In your case this could work:

```
STRTOK(STRTOK(column,':',2),',',1)
```

The first argument is the input string/column; the second the delimiter; and the third the observation number n.